# How to initialize a double array with various values using switch case in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a small doubt regarding array's. I am trying to implement a single dimensional array like what's shown below.

```
double [] test1; 
int value; // Which I will get it from DB
Switch (value){

case 1:
test1 = {1, 0, 0,1};
break;
case 2;
test1 = {0, 0, 0,1};
break;
case 3;
test1 = {0, 0, 1,1};
break;
case 4;
test1 = {1, 0, 1,1};
break;

}
```

I understood that what i have done is wrong from VS, but I could not find the way to do it correctly.

Could any one help me in solving this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `test1 = new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 };`?

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you just have to use `new` to initialize the arrays:

```
double [] test1; 
int value; // Which I will get it from DB
Switch (value){
case 1:
  test1 = new double[] {1, 0, 0,1};
  break;
case 2:
  test1 = new double[] {0, 0, 0,1};
  break;
case 3:
  test1 = new double[] {0, 0, 1,1};
  break;
case 4:
  test1 = new double[] {1, 0, 1,1};
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two immediate issues:

1. semi-colons instead of colons at the end of each case statement
2. the lack of 'new double[]' at the beginning of each array definition

e.g.

```
        double[] test1;
        int value = 1; 
        switch (value)
        {
            case 1:
                test1 = new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
                break;
            case 2:
                test1 = new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
                break;
            case 3:
                test1 = new double[] { 0, 0, 1, 1 };
                break;
            case 4:
                test1 = new double[] { 1, 0, 1, 1 };
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case statement where you are setting test1 make sure to create a new double[] when initializing it like so:

```
...
case 1:
test1 = new double [] { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
break;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify that its array. use the `new` keyword to create a new array. you can also do this.

```
case 1:
test1 = new [] { 1d, 0d, 0d, 1d };
break;
```